# Why does a RM ANOVA require more subjects than levels?

Tags: anova, repeated-measures

I have never completely understood the theory behind why you need to have more subjects than levels in a RM ANOVA. For example, I was using the package "ez" to run an ANOVA, and got an error because I had a one-way RM ANOVA that had 24 levels and only 8 subjects. I knew I would get the error, but I would like to conceptually understand why that is.

Edit: This is the error that I'm getting, in case it makes more sense than I do!

[image: ezANOVA error message]